# Cheap accommodation in London

Tags: budget, london, accommodation, lhr, hostels

I'm planning a two or three day stopover in London in early September. My main concern is accommodation for myself (young male adult) for two nights.

Are there any cheap but safe hostels not too far away from Heathrow Airport?

If I was to tour the city for two days, what would be an ideal place to live such that I could catch those hop-on hop-off bus tours?

1. By "not too far", I meant close enough such that I can use public transport to commute to/from LHR. To be clear, I'm quite comfortable with commuting.
2. My budget is $50-70 per night. In US/Canada, we get motels for these rates and that's what I'm using as a reference. Apologies if I'm completely off.
3. "Safe" means avoiding rough neighbourhoods.
4. What I'm specifically asking for is what neighbourhoods should I target.

Note: So far, I've looked at Hostelworld, Hostelbookers and YHA.

Comment: Why are you restricting yourself to just accommodation near Heathrow? It'd mean a long trip on the tube or bus every day to most things you might want to see!

Comment: There are a great many hostels for a great many different budget, convenience, and comfort levels in London. You can arrange rooms with many of them through HostelWorld or HostelBookers. What research have you done so far, and based on what criteria? (the definition of "cheap" and "safe," for example, can vary from person to person.)

Comment: What's your budget? What's "not too far" - 5km? 50?  Near Heathrow is not near where the bus tours go, for example...

Comment: agree with Gagravaar. You should stay near London instead.

Comment: updated question for clarification purposes

Answer (score 3):

I think you should checkout the [Youth Hostels Association](http://www.yha.org.uk/) website for "cheap" accommodation within the UK. Heathrow Airport is located a considerable distance from the London you wish to visit, so staying anywhere close to it is pointless.

An example of a Youth Hostel from the above website close to many amenities and the tour buses which you can take is close to Oxford Street in the heart of London, a description of it can be seen [here](http://www.yha.org.uk/hostel/london-oxford-street).

In terms of safety, London is no more safe and no more dangerous than any other big city in Europe or the Western World. But hey anything can happen. London is a great place but not cheap.